# Saving Video on Mobile - Hide or Show Video while saving it?

Tags: usability, mobile, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research

Quick and short question.

I'm building iOS Video Editor app. Within the Video Edit Screen I'm placing a "Save button" so the user can press Save quickly.

Do you think:

1) I should place the "saving" pop up in the middle of the screen, hiding the video and focusing on the saving process

2) Or should I place it below the video, on-top of the edit tools, and keep the video visible?

**Would love to hear your thoughts.
Roi**

Comment: Why would you obstruct the userʼs view at all?

Comment: @Crissov please elaborate?

Comment: You should show an indication that saving/downloading is in progress, but there is no UX reason to block the user from continuing to edit the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) Or should I place it below the video, on-top of the edit tools, and
>   keep the video visible?

I would go with this one, BUT you need to indicate that it is saving and saved in some way.

Some examples of how you can do that:

- Replacing the save icon with a loading one then a tick when it has saved which then goes back to a save icon.
- A small ribbon at the top that appears saying it has been saved.
- A quick overlay saying its saved, like the volume one in IOS works.

I don't think there would be a reason to obstruct the users view. Incase they want to do a quick save and continue editing.

Comment: This is exactly what I wasn't sure about. As pressing Save should make the save process the main thing, showing the video and saving might confuse the user as it doesn't focus the saving behavior (there is a cancel option also). After the video is done saving there is an option to share the video, but it is still hiding the video (on top of it), as I thought share is part of the save process. What do you think?

Comment: What is the cancel for? Why should it make it the main thing? Users mainly want to know and be assured its saved so they can carry on or exit. If there is a pop up or something interrupting the screen every time you save it asking if you want to share it could be irritating, the user will share it when they are ready to, so I'd be tempted to separate the two and have them next to each other on the edit tools.

Comment: Hey Owen, We have an IP on the app visuals. I'd like to share them with you separately. I've sent you a message via your website. Thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia Yes thats fine, I have replied, it maybe worth adding them here to as it might help with other answers.

Comment: Of course, I just need to talk with the legal department to make sure it's fine